# Xamarin.UITest find element in ios application using REPL and tree command

Tags: ios, xamarin, mobile, automation, read-eval-print-loop

I am trying to run IOS tests using xamarin. the same test automation is running on android.

tree:
[tree image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6eAR.png)
REPL tool after querying all elements :
app.Query(c=>c.All())
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpscP.png)

How to access element "toggle-menu-button".

Tried using app.Query(c=>c.Id("toggle-menu-button"))
app.Query(c=>c.Css("#toggle-menu-button"))

but no luck

I am trying to run IOS tests using xamarin. the same test automation is running on android.

tree:
[tree image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6eAR.png)
REPL tool after querying all elements :
app.Query(c=>c.All())
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpscP.png)

How to access element "toggle-menu-button".

Tried using app.Query(c=>c.Id("toggle-menu-button"))
app.Query(c=>c.Css("#toggle-menu-button"))

Comment: Here is the document about [Controlling the Application with Xamarin.UITest.IApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/frameworks/uitest/#controlling-the-application-with-xamarinuitestiapp). Did you try to use the `app.Query(c=>c.Marked("ValidateButton"))` method?

Comment: yes, but no luck.